# Spinner item small text invisible on some devices

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-spinner, android

I want to change the spinner item layout. The layout will have two TextViews. One with small size text, and the other with medium size text. The layout below is what I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="foo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="bar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This works great on my A500 tab with Ice Cream Sandwich installed. The spinner has a black background and the text has white text. However, if I use the exact same layout on a HTC Desire HD running 2.3.3, then the spinner background have changed to white. It is impossible to see the text, since this is also white.

Instead I could use `textAppearance{Small,Medium}Inverse` but then the situation will just be reversed. The text will be visible on HTC Desire but not on A500.

The question [changing spinner text color based on background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671413/changing-spinner-text-color-based-on-background-color) seems to have found a solution, but as far as I can tell, `textColorPrimary` is included in `textAppearance{Small,Medium}`.

I would like to use the same layout no matter what device or android version for maintainability reasons. What should I do?

Also, it would be great if I could use the exact same layout for ListView items, again for maintainability reasons.